# Can we make use of "Upcoming Events"?

Tags: discussion

There is a feature called 'Upcoming Events' that is used at [Space](https://space.stackexchange.com/), and possibly other sister sites.  Their [application of it is not completely without issue](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/550/how-do-the-upcoming-events-links-work) but it did get me wondering if we might make use of it some how.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's what I used for the one year party

Comment: @JohnCavan In that case you directed it to the meta post?

Answer (score 2):

I mentioned it in chat a while ago, but I think we should do some weekly topic challenges. There's a meta post about it here: [How do weekly topic challenges work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work)

Answer (score 2):

"Upcoming events" can be used (by mods) to link to any URL on the site for a designated period of time.  (On Mi Yodeya we link to tag pages for seasonally-appropriate topics.)  Events are different from [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) meta posts, both of which show up in the Community Bulletin.

Events could be used (in lieu of featured tags) for weekly topic challenges, or contests (like the one we just had), or any other time-bound thing we want to highlight.  I can't think of any right now, but if you have suggestions, please make them.